# div height needs to grow based on div next to it

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's the url to the page:
http://whiterootmedia.com/test
I need the right brown div to grow when the grey div content expands. I'm vertically repeating a background image in the brown div.

```
<body style="margin: 0px; min-width: 700px; height: 100%;">
    <div class="site" style="background: yellow; min-width: 577px; height: 100%;">
        <div class="banner" style="background: blue; height: 100px; width: 417px; float: left;">
            Banner Banner Banner Banner Banner
        </div>
        <div class="body_container" style="background: pink; height: 100%;">
            <div class="ads" style="background: brown; width: 160px; position: absolute; right: 0px; height: 100%; clear: left;">
                Ads Ads Ads Ads Ads Ads Ads Ads Ads
            </div>
            <div class="tree" style="background: grey; white-space: nowrap; width: auto; min-width: 417px; clear: left;">
                Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content
                <br />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grass" style="background: green; height: 100px;">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Give the header a fixed height and you're all set to go.

Comment: can you expain or shoot me an example?

Comment: Are you talking about the red `<div>`? You'd like to give it `100%` height relative to the body, right?

Comment: yeah but I can't get it to work for some reason

Comment: I simplified the code on http://www.whiterootmedia.com/test

Comment: I would seriously consider using a stylesheet for your CSS, as inline styles are a pain to read and edit.

Comment: I layer my css. I use inline for examples so it's easier to read... in my opinion. But I'm about to give up on this. It sux bcuz it doesn't seem to hard. Thx for all ur help so far!

Comment: So, um, what do you want your end result to look like? I'm a little confused.

Answer (score 4):

The classic way of doing this is using a technique called [Faux Columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/).

The idea is to put the repeating background image on the container, and `background-position: 100% 0` to put it on the right side and make it look like it's the background of the right column. (The right column would have a transparent background.)

You don't need to worry about the height of the column, since the background fills the height of the container instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this script

```
var tree_height = $('.tree').height();
var tree_top = $('.tree').offset().top;
var ads_height = tree_height + tree_top ;
$('.ads').css('height',ads_height);
```

Answer (score -1):

there is easy way, set `overflow: hidden` for wrapper and for columns set `padding-bottom: 9999px; margin-bottom: -9999px;`